# Putting a DynamoDB item if it doesn't exist, or does with identical values

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, atomic

I'm trying to write some code which puts an item into a dynamo database under two conditions:

1. The primary key doesn't exist yet
2. It does exist, and it's values are the same as my inputs

I tried to use the following code:

```py
table.put_item(
    Item={
        'example': 'foobar'
    },
    ConditionExpression='attribute_not_exists(example) OR (example = :value)',
    ExpressionAttributeValues={
        ':value': {'S': 'foobar'}
    }
)
```

This works fine when the item does not exist, but the second part of the condition expression always seems to fail:

`(example = :value)`

For the purpose of this question, assume the database has the following:

```json
[
    {'example': 'foobar'}
]
```

Is there something wrong with my condition expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [doc](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Table.put_item), the `put_item` action of the `Table` resource accepts the following as input for the `ExpressionAttributeValues` param:

```
ExpressionAttributeValues={
    'string': 'string'|123|Binary(b'bytes')|True|None|set(['string'])|set([123])|set([Binary(b'bytes')])|[]|{}
}
```

Therefore, change from

```
    ExpressionAttributeValues={
        ':value': {'S': 'foobar'}
    }
```

to

```
    ExpressionAttributeValues={
        ':value': 'foobar'
    }
```

will work.

Comment: Yep, that did it! Must have arrived at the incorrect syntax by looking at a couple articles.